# Where to save files in ftp host

Tags: ftp, hosts

I'm planing to save some files in my ftp account.

This is the directory:

```
/Root
  ├─ some .folders
  ├─ some domain_folders
  ├─ some server_folders
  └─ folder I want to create to save files
```

**My question is: can I create the folder there in root next to my domain and the others without making errors on the server? or is it a Bad Thing?**

If I can do that then won't the files be exposed to the Internet? Won't they be accessible via an IP or something?

If I can't do that I was planning to use WordPress on a domain to use it as a file manager.

**Is there something like [this](https://codecanyon.net/item/bedrive-file-sharing-and-cloud-storage/12700384) for WordPress where I can log in and only have access to a file manager?**

Comment: Short answer : You won't experience any *errors* or anything remotely next to *bad* if you place your folders in the root directory. On the contrary, webmasters use the root directory to make certain files or folders directly inaccessible to the public view.

However, do not be lulled into a false sense of security believing that those files are completely inaccessible. Using `../`, people could manage to view those files.

Comment: @Don'tRoothereplz... only if he's using an incorrectly configured PHP file manager script. Apache2 won't ever let you browse up a directory from the configured root of the domain

Comment: @td512 Yes, that's right. Unfortunately, I've seen too many sites where the root can be accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't like saving files to a directory in root--but there's absolutely nothing wrong with it. I just like a clean root directory.

But yes, as long as your FTP server is set up correctly, it will prevent any attempts to look at other files on the system. Set up properly, the FTP server is not able to access anything outside of its defined area. However, because there are many ftp servers out there with different configuration options, it's not really possible to tell you how to set it up--configuration is different with different server software.

When I set up an FTP server, I also use a security group "ftpusers," and that group only has access to the specific folder, and I do NOT allow people to log in with their regular logon credentials for that server. All other folders are excluded. You still have to protect your server from other types of attack (privilege elevation and the like), but this is a safe configuration from attempts to see the root folder with "../.".